# Python sort a list of dicts using a specified mapping

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, mapping

So, I have a list of dicts in python that looks like this:

```
lis =
[
{'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something', 'Genre': 10, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'},
{'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something Else', 'Genre': 20, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'}
...
]
```

Now I want `lis` to be in a way, such that **each individual dict** is ordered using the `mapping` for the keys that I will provide. For example, if

```
mapping = {1:'date', 2:'Genre', 3:'action', 4:'type'}
```

Then, I want to make my original list of dicts look like this:

```
lis =
[
{'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37', 'Genre': 10, 'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something'},
{'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37', 'Genre': 20, 'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something Else'}
...
]
```

How do I implement this?

Comment: So you want to custom sort your dicts?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Python dicts were originally unordered.  At some point that was changed, so that they maintain the order in which the keys were added.  Control over the order is weak though.   If you want to change it, you need to create a new list, adding the keys in the desired order, or you can delete them and re-add them from the existing dict.

Comment: Why not use a list for mapping?

Comment: Your mapping is backwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```py
lis = [
{'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something', 'Genre': 10, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'},
{'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something Else', 'Genre': 20, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'}
]

mapping = {1:'date', 2:'Genre', 3:'action', 4:'type'}

sorted_lis = [
    {field: record[field] for field in mapping.values()}
    for record in lis
]

print(sorted_lis)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my purpose in an elegant manner, without imports. Are there any downsides with regards to performance?

Comment: @DebapratimChakraborty This, I cannot tell, sorry.  It might be the case that `OrderedDict` are faster. Still, I tried with a list comprehension on a 10^6 element list (duplicates of your items in your list) and it terminated within 1.25 sec so it seems reasonably fast.

Answer (score 2):

You might harness [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for this task as follows

```
import collections
order = ['date', 'Genre', 'action', 'type']
dct1 = {'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something', 'Genre': 10, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'}
dct2 = {'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something Else', 'Genre': 20, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'}
odct1 = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(order)
odct1.update(dct1)
odct2 = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(order)
odct2.update(dct2)
print(odct1)
print(odct2)
```

output:

```
OrderedDict([('date', '2021-05-07 01:59:37'), ('Genre', 10), ('action', 'Notify'), ('type', 'Something')])
OrderedDict([('date', '2021-05-07 01:59:37'), ('Genre', 20), ('action', 'Notify'), ('type', 'Something Else')])
```

Disclaimer: this assume every dict you want to process has exactly all keys from `order`. This solution works with any python version which has `collections.OrderedDict` if you will be using solely `python3.7` or newer you might use common `dict` as follows

```
order = ['date', 'Genre', 'action', 'type']
dct1 = dict.fromkeys(order)
dct1.update({'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something', 'Genre': 10, 'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37'})
print(dct1)
```

output

```
{'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37', 'Genre': 10, 'action': 'Notify', 'type': 'Something'}
```

Disclaimer still holds

Comment: `OrderedDict` is not necessary for this in newer versions of Python

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def sort_dct(li, mapping):
    return {v: li[v] for k,v in mapping.items()}

out = []
mapping = {1:'date', 2:'Genre', 3:'action', 4:'type'}
for li in lis:
    out.append(sort_dct(li,mapping))
    
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[{'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37',
  'Genre': 10,
  'action': 'Notify',
  'type': 'Something'},
 {'date': '2021-05-07 01:59:37',
  'Genre': 20,
  'action': 'Notify',
  'type': 'Something Else'}]
```